# Error uninstalling ADT version 22.3.0

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, uninstallation

To install ADT version 23.0.4, first need to uninstall ADT 22.3.0. When I tried to uninstall it, I got the following error:

```
An error occurred while uninstalling
session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Uninstall, operand=[R]org.eclipse.rcp.configuration_root.win32.win32.x86_64 1.0.0.M20130204-1200 --> null, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.natives.actions.CleanupzipAction).
Backup of file E:\Softwares\Android\eclipse\eclipse.exe failed.
Can not remove : E:\Softwares\Android\eclipse\eclipse.exe
```

Unless I don't uninstall ADT 22.3.0, I can't install ATD 23.0.4, but unistalling giving the above error!

Comment: Why do you need to uninstall this and why does it seem that it's trying to uninstall eclipse instead of just a plugin? Run eclipse as administrator could help, the error message is about permissions.

Comment: I need to uninstall it because i want to install new version  of ADT 23.3.0, otherwise dependency issues appears if I don't uninstall ADT 22.3.0